# Aspose.Cells .NET: upgrading 6.0.1 to 7.3.1, WorkBookDesigner.SetDataSource() fails

Tags: cells, aspose, aspose-cells

Scenario: add two DataSets by invoking WorkBookDesigner.SetDataSource(DataSet) twice, each of the DataSets has a DataTable of customers, the DataTables have different names.

**6.0.1: worked fine**

**7.3.1: Exception**

Test method Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose.Tests.Cells.AsposeCellsEngineTests.Execute_Report_NoTemplate_TemplateTypeDesigner_FormatXLS_ReturnsEmptySpreadSheet threw exception: 
Nirvana.Reporting.Core.ReportExecutionException: An error occured executing report 'CustomerList' ---> System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'PHONENUMBERS'  Key being added: 'PHONENUMBERS'

```
System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)
Aspose.Cells.WorkbookDesigner.SetDataSource(DataTable dataTable)
Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose.Cells.AsposeCellsEngine.AssignDataSourcesToWorkbookDesigner(IReport report, WorkbookDesigner designer) in C:\Workspaces\ja38524\KBC.ServiceOrganisation\Framework\Trunk\Source\Nirvana.Solution\Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose\Cells\AsposeCellsEngine.cs: line 344
Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose.Cells.AsposeCellsEngine.ExecuteDesignerReport(IReport report) in C:\Workspaces\ja38524\KBC.ServiceOrganisation\Framework\Trunk\Source\Nirvana.Solution\Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose\Cells\AsposeCellsEngine.cs: line 298
Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose.Cells.AsposeCellsEngine.Execute(Guid reportInstanceId, IReport report) in C:\Workspaces\ja38524\KBC.ServiceOrganisation\Framework\Trunk\Source\Nirvana.Solution\Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose\Cells\AsposeCellsEngine.cs: line 103
Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose.Cells.AsposeCellsEngine.Execute(Guid reportInstanceId, IReport report) in C:\Workspaces\ja38524\KBC.ServiceOrganisation\Framework\Trunk\Source\Nirvana.Solution\Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose\Cells\AsposeCellsEngine.cs: line 120
Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose.Tests.Cells.AsposeCellsEngineTests.Execute_Report_NoTemplate_TemplateTypeDesigner_FormatXLS_ReturnsEmptySpreadSheet() in C:\Workspaces\ja38524\KBC.ServiceOrganisation\Framework\Trunk\Source\Nirvana.Solution\Nirvana.Reporting.Engines.Aspose.Tests\Cells\AsposeCellsEngineTest.cs: line 188
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks like a regression but it might be solved in latest versions. So, you should give a try to latest version: Aspose.Cells for .NET 8.4.2 and see if it makes any difference.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*